# Whats the best solution for a database used in conjunction with Maps in Android?

Tags: android, database, google-maps

Could someone please point me in the right direction. My project involves a database where users enter their address and other info from my website. This database is then referenced in my android application to show the locations of these addresses in my database.

I have yet to start and just came up with this idea. My question is, what would be the best method to create a database easily modified through my website (mySQL, php, etc), and also easily referenced easily through Android and the Google Maps API? I need some ideas on the languages I will need to use to create this database and website so I can go buy the necessary books to start reading up.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way for you to go with this one is:

- a database cache on the device

  - that means you can use XML if you don't have many complicated requirements from storing the address
  - or SQLite if you want to be able to query the database and do more fancy things
- on the server side

  - if you only need to get the data from your server on the device, then a simple XML with a unique address per user should do it
  - if you need to push addresses from your device to the server then a REST system needs to be implemented

So, now you just need to figure out exactly what you need from your system and then start googleing on one of the solutions I gave you! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine would probably work for that. GAE supports Java and Python. Maybe use the Restlet framework (compatible with GAE) to implement a REST architecture.